# How to restart yarn on AWS EMR

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, emr

I am using Hadoop 2.6.0 (`emr-4.2.0` image). I have made some changes in `yarn-site.xml` and want to restart yarn to bring the changes into effect.

Is there a command using which I can do this?

Answer (score 28):

***Edit (10/26/2017):*** A more detailed Knowledge Center article on how to do this has been published here by AWS officially - 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restart-service-emr/.

You can ssh into the master node of your EMR cluster and run -

```
"sudo /sbin/stop hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager"
"sudo /sbin/start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager"
```

commands to restart the Yarn resource manager. EMR AMI 4.x.x uses upstart - /sbin/{start,stop,restart} are all symlinks to /sbin/initctl, which is part of upstart. See the [initctl](http://linux.die.net/man/8/initctl) man page for more information.

Alternatively, you can follow the instructions here to propagate your changes to yarn-site.xml - [yarn-change-configuration-on-yarn-site-xml](http://hvivani.com.ar/2014/10/30/yarn-change-configuration-on-yarn-site-xml-and-replicate-to-all-the-nodes/)

Answer (score 26):

For those who are gonna come from Google

In order to restart a service in EMR, perform the following actions:

- Find the name of the service by running the following command:

  ```
  initctl list
  ```

For example, the YARN Resource Manager service is named `hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager`.

- Stop the service by running the following command:

  ```
  sudo stop hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
  ```
- Wait a few seconds, then start the service by running the following command:

  ```
  sudo start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
  ```

Note: Stop/start is required; do not use the restart command.

- Verify that the process is running by running the following command:

  ```
  sudo status hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
  ```

Check for the process using ps, and then check the log file for any errors in the log directory /var/log/.

Source : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restart-service-emr/

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to enable log-aggregation, it is actually easier to create the cluster with log-aggregation already enabled, as described in the documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html

(It is actually enabled by default if you are using `emr-4.3.0`).

Answer (score -2):

Try restarting this service as well:

hadoop-yarn-nodemanager